# Issue with my own routes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a method on my controller (admin/highlights_controller) like this:

```
def process
    @checkIfExists =  Highlight.where(year: params[:year], highlight_category:params[:highlight_category])

    if @checkIfExists.count > 0
      redirect_to admin_highlight_path(@checkIfExists.first)  
    else
      redirect_to new_admin_highlight_path(year: params[:year], highlight_category:params[:highlight_category])
    end
end
```

And in my routes I created:

```
get '/admin/highlight', to: 'admin/highlights#process', as: 'highlights_process'
```

In another View I want to link to this method I created, im doing this:

```
<%= link_to year.year, highlights_process(year: year.id, highlight_category: highlight_category.id) %>
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined method `highlights_process' for #<#<Class:0x007faee6309bb0>:0x007faee7813d30>
```

What Im doing wrong? When I do a rake routes I get that route was created correctly.

```
   highlights_process GET    /admin/highlight(.:format) admin/highlights#process
```

Comment: try `highlights_process_path(year: year.id, highlight_category: highlight_category.id)` You have probably forgotten the `_ path` suffix to your route

Comment: Perfect Maxence. You were right. But now Im getting another king of error. I modify my view with this: 

 <%= link_to year.year, highlights_process_path(year.id, highlight_category.id) %> 

And my controller with this: 

  def process(year,highlight_category)

But now im getting another error: 

wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: Is your route a `member` or a `collection`, ie do you have to pass highlight id to get to the process action of highlights controller ?

Comment: Doesnt get it. The only thing I wanto to do in this method process is, if theres already a Highlight with this year and highlight_category, go to edit page. If not, go to create page. I was clear?

Comment: Your route is not expecting an id, then I am not very sure why it says "1 for 2", all params you pass are extra params not required params. Just make then optional like this : `highlights_process_path(year: year.id, highlight_category: highlight_category.id)` instead of `link_to year.year, highlights_process_path(year.id, highlight_category.id)` and also you should read the guide about routing, it will help you a lot : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. Especially this bit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions which deals with extra RESTful actions

Comment: Thanks Maxence. It was optional before, and I changed trying to make it works. BTW doesnt make difference and the error is the same. :/ I will read the article. thanks